Vimeo SDK fails to upload a text track (captions or subtitles)
I want to upload a text track to Vimeo with the Python SDK. I follow the documentation at the bottom of this page:
v.upload_texttrack('/videos/12345', 'captions', 'en-US', 'your-texttrack.vtt')

and I get this cryptic error:
vimeo.exceptions.TexttrackCreationFailure: The application has received an invalid parameter. Please get in touch with the app's creator.

I could not find any solutions with a web search.
How can I solve this error and upload a subtitle file to Vimeo programmatically?

You need to capitalize the last two letters of the language, as in the sample code:
en-US

will work, while:
en-us

it may not. The error message is indeed less than helpful.
If that still fails, e.g. fr-FR, try removing the country code. After I raised a ticket, Vimeo Support wrote:

It looks like the language code 'fr-FR' is not being accepted, could try using just 'fr' and let us know if you are still having an issue?

And indeed, uploading with just fr works.
